# Using Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) to handle uneven clusters where some subjects have more outcomes than others

Tags: logistic, generalized-estimating-equations, cluster-sample

If possible, I would like to use GEE to control for clusters in my data where some subjects have more measurement and outcome pairs than others. In this particular case, the outcome is binary and the predictor variable is a continuous measure.

More specifically, we are looking at how a continuous measure X relates to having a successful vs. unsuccessful pregnancy. However, each subject in the study can have a different number of pregnancies (with varying associated outcomes). The X value is measured prior to each individual pregnancy and associated with the outcome for that pregnancy.

Does it seem reasonable to use a binary logistic GEE model to control for this sort of within-subject clustering to determine if X has an effect on the pregnancy outcome? I have some follow-up  questions about determining the appropriate correlation matric to use if so.

If there is a better method than GEE for this sort of analysis, I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks in advance!